# SSH in local network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have about 50 computers that I need to be able to establish ssh connection. But I have to do it without typing each person's password while doing ssh-copy-id. I tried to disable password authorization in ssh but it doesn't work, still asks for a password. I know each IP but I think if there is any way to connect without a password at all? It's also acceptable if ill go to every person and ask them to enter their password on their PC. Thanks

Comment: Add id-rsa.pub key of your machine to every users autorized_keys.

Comment: Tried, i still need to enter password at least once for first connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `ssh-copy-id(1)`:

> By default it adds the keys by appending them to the remote user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (creating the file, and directory, if necessary).

Since all ssh-copy-id does is copy your public key (usually `ssh-keygen` will create it in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, if you want to avoid entering the 50 passwords in ssh-copy-id you just have to find a way to append your key to the 50 files. I can think of multiple methods for this:

1. Go physically to every machine with an thumb drive containing your pubkey and copy it by hand
2. Prepare an authorized_keys file, set up an anonymous ftp server (or probably any other kind of server) with the right rights and push it through there (will only work if you're certain you don't care about any data that could have been written to a preexisting file)
3. If you have one already setup, use a deployment tool
4. If each machine has a user, you could go the other way around, setup your machine with a file/web server, put you pubkey on it with a script/binary that fetches the key from the server and adds it at the bottom of the authorized_keys file and ask every user to download and execute the file
5. There's probably other possible methods, those seems like the easiest to me though

Answer (score 1):

You can login in a remote linux by ssh without password using 'ssh-keygen' and 'ssh-copy-id':

1.- Create public and private keys using ssh-key-gen on local-host:

```
ssh-keygen
```

2.- Copy the public key to remote-host using ssh-copy-id

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
```

3.- Login to remote-host without entering the password

```
ssh remote-host
```

You have more information in [this documentation](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-use-ssh-public-key-authentication/).

Comment: ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@192.168.88.83
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
user@192.168.88.83's password:
Still asks for pass, maybe i need to configure ssh on remote host somehow?